# Django SelectDateWidget issue

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using django SelectDateWidget and it works perfectly, except one case.

If I enter invalid date like 31th of June 1985, then fields become empty.

How can I do it, so that even invalid data are shown?

Comment: You *could* hack out your own widget based on the built-in one... but then what happens? Eventually you need this input to be formatted as a date object. So why allow invalid input in the widget only to face the same problem at the form validation step and then again when you try to store the record? But if you must... https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/extras/widgets.py

Comment: You can add an event listener on the empty field or extend the `SelectDateWidget`